# How to reduce surface friction when pushing a gear sideways in shaft direction

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design

I'm thinking of a system where a gear engages and disengages by shifting it along the shaft axis. I want to use an arm/board from a servo to push the gear in and out of position, but I'm worried about the friction applied to the side face of the gear. How would I go about reducing/eliminating this? Is there a open side bearing, sort of like half lazy susan with hole in the middle? Do I have to design a custom bearing embedded into the arm?

Also, if I am to use dog clutch instead, how do you deal with friction between the clutch and the arm holding it?

Answer (score 1):

Gearboxes often use grooves in the gear and brass or bronze forks to slide the gears.

Also gears are often mounted on bushes to the shaft they run on.

Perhaps sourcing an old box or two and taking them apart to see would be useful.

Comment: Right, but I was worried about the friction from the contact points more specifically. Do the forks just make contact with the gears directly with only lube?

Comment: @lascooter the gear oil is splashed about liberally on manual and pumped on auto, but forced lubrication might be used on manual for specifuc reasons.